# DSpace login password keeps breaking/changing?

Tags: passwords, reset, dspace

Mind you, this is a sandbox installation created by my professor so I inherited it as she had it set up. And I've had trouble with it since early on.

Initially, the password I chose worked. Then one day, I tried to login but I had the "wrong password". I was certain I didn't but I attempted to reset the password. Couldn't. My email address couldn't be located. I contacted my professor who sent a reset email to me and advised me to choose a password I wouldn't forget...

Next password I could not forget, I use it for a few other things. Within a week, can't login. Wrong password. Try to reset, can't. Email can't be found. I email her again, she again insists I choose a password I won't forget and sends me a reset email. And this time, I use the exact password she suggested I use.

I've been working on my project this entire day, logging in repeatedly when logged out due to inactivity. And just now....yeah, kicked out. Wrong password. Can't reset. I've changed almost NOTHING in the backend and the first few times this happened, I had changed literally NOTHING. The only change I made was to my search index so I switched it back to the original file. Still broken.

This isn't me. I hate having to ask her for help again because she seems to think I'm just stupidly forgetting my password every other day. I'm not. What could be causing this?

Update: Asked my professor, she said she can log in just fine. She suggested I try different browsers in case there was any confusion since my login is my school email but the passwords are different. Gave it a shot - tried Explorer, Edge, and Firefox, no go. Tried my husband's Macbook via Safari and still can't get in. She agreed that the small changes I did make are irrelevant. I'm still locked out but at least she doesn't think I'm stupid enough to forget my password repeatedly...

Comment: Check the DSpace log file for any messages. The only thing I can think of is that DSpace does some IP checks and if your IP address keeps changing between requests (eg if there is a proxy / load balancer involved somewhere) it might not let you authenticate.